# What is the difference between self and $this in php?

Tags: php, oop

What is the difference between `$this` and `self`? When should we use each of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$this` refers to the current **instance**. `self` refers to the current **class**.

In other words, you can use `$this->someMember` to refer to an instance member and `self::$someStaticMember` to refer to a static member.

Answer (score 0):

$this points to current object where as self:: points to current class.